# Hamming bound vs Singleton bound for a (5, 3) code

Tags: combinatorics, coding-theory

I have encounter a problem for comparing Hamming bound and Singleton bound for a (5, 3) code, i.e.length n = 5 and minimum distance d = 3, for different cases of q (number of elements).

After calculation by using the definition, when q = 2, Hamming bound equal to around 5.33, while Singleton bound equal to 8.

When q = 3, Hamming bound equal to around 22.1 while Singleton bound equal to 27.

Both bounds are the same at q = 4.

Then at q larger than or equal to 5, Hamming bound is larger than Singleton Bound.

According to the wikipedia on Hamming bound, it said that the "Hamming bound is a limit on the parameters of an arbitrary block code. A code that attains the Hamming bound is said to be a perfect code."

From Wikipedia, it seems that the Hamming bound should have the largest value than all other bounds, i.e. the Singleton, however, this is not the case for the (5, 3) code for q = 2 and q = 3.

I couldn't figure out why this happens, can anyone please give me some hints? Thank you!

Comment: Let $A$ be the size of the largest code, let $H$ be the Hamming bound, and let $S$ be the singleton bound. You have three pieces of information: (1) $A\le H$. (2) $A\le S$. (3) When $A=H$, we say the code attaining $A$ is perfect. You are claiming that these three statements are contradictory, but I see no contradiction there. Can you elaborate? Why should those three imply $H\ge S$?

Comment: To put it simply; both the Hamming bound and Singleton bound are upper bounds for the size of a code. That implies nothing about the relation of the Hamilton and Singleton bounds to each other.

Comment: @MikeEarnest I get it now, its like different bounds n not really related to each other, thanks for your explanation!

Comment: Every code satisfies both the bounds, one is just looser than the other. In general the Singleton bound is rather useless (there are exceptions, most notably when $q$ is larger).

Comment: Thank you for explaining

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I can explain your confusion clearly. Let $A$ denote the maximum size of a code, let $H$ be the Hamming bound, and let $S$ be the singleton bound (all of these depend on parameters $n,q$ and $d$, but I omit them in the notation for clarity).

You know that $A\le H$ and $A\le S$. Furthermore, you know that *if a perfect code exists*, then it must be true that $A=H$, from which you can conclude $H\le S$. **However**, when a perfect code does not exist, you cannot conclude $H\le S$. In the cases your brought up, with $n=5,d=3,$ and $q\ge 5$, your computations show that no perfect code code (achieving the Hamming bound) can exist.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard about the fact that Hamming bound should have the largest value.
Moreover, i don't understand "the largest value" of what. Both bounds use q, n, d and the code cardinality: they can be used, if we have 3 of them, to have an upper/lower limit to the other one.

Comment: because wikipedia and other web sources said any code attains the value of hamming bound, then that is the perfect code, which implies that the hamming bound should be greatest? I guess? What i mean of  "the largest value" is meaning that singleton bound is smaller or equal to Hamming bound for all given n, q, d.